# XSLT/XML Making a cafe menu, with 2 foreach

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

Basically I've been trying to get a menu that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w775Z.png
(EDIT - Sorry about the language in the code, I can translate everything into english if needed)

But with the code I am using it only shows the 2 green lines https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs1Hc.png , leaving out the "dishes"(in the teal line) that you can order. If I remove the first foreach, it correctly puts out the dishes (without the green line-info).

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="meniu.xsl" ?>
<meniu>
<laikas>
<kas>PUSRYČIAI</kas>
<patiekalas>
<pavadinimas>SUMUŠTINIAI SU SŪDYTA LAŠIŠA</pavadinimas>
<kaina>12 Lt</kaina>
<aprasymas>skrudinta balta duona, žalias padažas, alyvuogės, lašiša, citrina</aprasymas>
<kalorijos>650</kalorijos>
</patiekalas>
<patiekalas>
<pavadinimas>KAIMIŠKA KIAUŠINIENĖ</pavadinimas>
<kaina>11 Lt</kaina>
<aprasymas>kepti kiaušiniai, rūkyta šoninė, šviežios daržovės, skrudinta duona</aprasymas>
<kalorijos>880</kalorijos>
</patiekalas>
</laikas>
<laikas>
<kas>PIETŪS</kas>
<patiekalas>
<pavadinimas>SUMUŠTINIAI SU SŪDYTA LAŠIŠA</pavadinimas>
<kaina>12 Lt</kaina>
<aprasymas>skrudinta balta duona, žalias padažas, alyvuogės, lašiša, citrina</aprasymas>
<kalorijos>650</kalorijos>
</patiekalas>
</laikas>
</meniu>
```

My XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body style="font-family:Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12pt; background-    color:#EEEEEE">
<xsl:for-each select="meniu/laikas">
<div style="background-color:green;color:black;padding:4px">
<span style="font-weight:bold;color:white"><xsl:value-of select="kas" /></span>
</div>
<xsl:for-each select="meniu/laikas/patiekalas">
<div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
<span style="font-weight:bold;color:white"><xsl:value-of select="pavadinimas" /></span>
<span style="margin-left:10px;font-size:10pt"><xsl:value-of select="kaina" /></span>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt"><xsl:value-of
select="aprasymas" />
<span style="font-style:italic">(<xsl:value-of select="kalorijos" /> kalorijų)
</span>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the XPath-Selector of the second `<for-each />` to `./patiekalas`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="patiekalas">
```

This is because inside the first `<for-each />` the context-node is the respective `meniu/laikas`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, and it actually worked! Thanks a lot, I guess I was actually doing SOMEWHAT the right thing!

Comment: Since I am sitting here waiting to mark this as a correct answer, could you also tell me how to add a little space between the teal and green bars?

Comment: Hi! I think this is a CSS issue. Try to add a `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` where applicable.